# Can Apache FOP be used to convert an arbitary HTML to PDF?

Tags: html, pdf, apache-fop

I have tried to use Apache FOP to convert HTML to PDF. ( HTML -->XHTML--> XSL-FO --> PDF). I used the xhtml2fo.xsl from Antenna House for the xhtml --> XSL-FO conversion.

It works for simple html files.

It does **not** work for html files with styling ( via embedded css or by style attribute). A PDF is created but completely unformatted. I am trying to convert HTML file where I do not have much control over the styling/content.

Creating an xslt for each html is not practical in my use-case.

Currently, I do have a working implementation with flyingsaucer. However, the requirement calls for an implementation without AGPL license.

My Question is: Can this be achieved with FOP ?

Appreciate any help

Comment: FWIW, AH Formatter (in its CSS flavor) can format HTML directly.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr version:**

In the most general situation, **no**, you cannot use FOP to convert **any** html preserving the original styles (and changing formatter would not solve the problem).

However, you can use FOP (or any another formatter) to try and handle reasonably well a large subset of html documents; this could require some XSLT adjustment.

---

### Why it cannot work in general

> HTML --> XHTML --> **XSL-FO --> PDF**

Your description of the necessary transformation chain is spot on.

However, **FOP is only involved in the last step**: with the exception of the features that are not implemented yet, the final PDF file should respect the typographical characteristics expressed in the FO file.

> I used the xhtml2fo.xsl from Antenna House for the xhtml --> XSL-FO conversion
> [...]
>
> A PDF is created but completely unformatted

Is the stylesheet you are using [this one from the AntennaHouse site](https://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/sample-xsl-xhtml2fo/xhtml2fo.xsl)?

From a quick look, it seems like it *should* convert the `style="..."` attribute producing separate attributes in the FO output, but **it does not process external CSS files**.

As a result, the HTML files styled with external CSS will be transformed into FO files without any formatting attribute (`font-family`, `font-size`, `text-align`, ...).

> Can this be achieved with FOP ?

If that's indeed the case, the formatter cannot do anything but **use the default values**, a few of which (`font-family` comes to mind) are application-dependant.

So, according to the formatter you use you will have a *slightly* different result, but still an "unformatted" one.

**What you need** is either a tool to "merge" the html and css files, inlining the styles so that the XSLT can process them, or a different stylesheet capable of taking into account the external css files (but I suspect it would not be easy to write one working in a general case).

### What can be fixed with little effort

While processing html tables the linked XSLT uses the `fo:table-and-caption` element, which is not supported by FOP so the tables "disappear" from the output.

This can be fixed with a small change in the XSLT, or (probably a cleaner solution) using a custom stylesheet importing the other one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:include href="xhtml2fo.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="html:table" priority="2">
    <fo:table xsl:use-attribute-sets="table">
      <!-- warning: table caption is not processed! -->
      <xsl:call-template name="process-table"/>
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is possible that the stylesheet you are actually using needs a few similar adjustments to better work in conjunction with FOP.

*Disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It wasn't that particular xsl. I tried the one from your link. It does not look that that supports html tables. The other xsl that I had supported tables however, it does not seem to support some style params( for ex: border)

Comment: The following is the html I tried to convert `code`<div style="width: 700px;">
<h2>This is the header</h2>
<table style="width: 700px;height:400px;border: 1px solid #4C4C4C;">
<tr> <td style="height:auto;vertical-align:top;">test 123<br/>
<table style="width: 100%;vertical-align:top;border: 5px solid #F00"cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>V1</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table></td></tr></table></div>`code`

Comment: @B.Abraham Answer updated with a solution for the tables.