# Conversion of html to pdf using java

Tags: java, html2pdf, html-to-pdf, pdf-conversion, openhtmltopdf

I want to convert **html response to pdf file using JAVA**. But the problem is that the HTML page contains some JSON part which creates a problem and throws an error while converting it to pdf. So, I want some possible solution in java to convert a mixture of HTML and JSON into a pdf file.
Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried java library htmltopdf converter but it's throwing an error due to JSON value in HTML.

Comment: please consider adding exactly what you have done and the errors you got

Comment: It could be worth looking at [apache fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728428/can-apache-fop-be-used-to-convert-an-arbitary-html-to-pdf), you might get the desired result, but it won't come for free, you'd have to hand-wire html/json-> fop xml mappings.

Comment: Kind of curious what that JSON part looks like.  You should post a sample of the HTML you are trying to process.