# HTML table are not coming on PDF using xhtml2fo.xsl

Tags: pdf, xhtml, xsl-fo, apache-fop

The HTML tables are not coming on the PDF when converting it using xhtml2fo.xsl.

This the HTML page(Sampler.html) location:
https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/6895749/uploads/XSL%20Sample/sample-xhtml.zip?hsLang=en

This the XSL(xhtml2fo.xsl) location:
https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/6895749/uploads/XSL%20Sample/sample-xsl-xhtml2fo.zip?hsLang=en

All the contents are coming, but the tables are not coming on PDF. What can I do?

Comment: based on your links the table should be processed.
Did you do any debugging?

Comment: Based on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728428/can-apache-fop-be-used-to-convert-an-arbitary-html-to-pdf, we need to do some change to table to come on PDF.

Comment: I transformed `Sampler.html` with `xhtml2fo.xsl` using the XSLT processor in the AH Formatter GUI on Windows and using both a standalone XSLT 1.0 and a standalone XSLT 2.0 processor. I got the same three tables in the output every time. What are you using to do the XSL transformation? On which operating system?

Comment: Which formatter are you using (AH, FOP, ...)? _If_ you are using FOP: the template matching `html:table` creates an `fo:table-and-caption` element, which FOP does not manage; you can modify that template to create just an `fo:table` instead (and use a block for the caption, if you need it).

Comment: Formatter is FOP. I will try that. Thanks